# Falha na leitura de char com scanf ("%c")

Tags: c, char, scanf

Verifiquem esse código para cadastrar duas matrizes aleatórias e então somar, multiplicar...
Quero colocar uma opção que a cada operação feita o usuário tem a opção de sair do programa, sem voltar ao menu incial, colocando para ele escolher entre 1 e 2 funcionou, mas quando coloco para escolher entre S ou N não da certo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef M[50][50];

void verificar_matriz (int l, int c, M matriz, int *);

void sair_menu (int *);

void receber_matriz (int l, int c, M A)
 {
int linha,coluna;
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1) ; linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        printf ("\nInsira o numero da Matriz[%d][%d]: ", linha, coluna);
        scanf ("%d", &A[linha][coluna]);
    }
}

system("cls");

printf ("\nMatriz: \n\n");

for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha ++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        printf("%d",A[linha][coluna]);
        printf("  ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

void receber_matriz_ale1 (int l, int c, M matriz)
{
int linha,coluna;
srand(time(NULL));
printf ("\nMatriz Aleatoria A: \n\n");
for (linha = 1;linha < (l+1);linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1;coluna < (c+1);coluna++)
    {
        matriz[linha][coluna] = rand()%10;
    }
}
for (linha = 1;linha < (l+1);linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1;coluna < (c+1);coluna++)
    {
        printf("%5d",matriz[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
}

void receber_matriz_ale2 (int l, int c, M matriz)
{
int linha,coluna;
srand(time(NULL));
printf ("\nMatriz Aleatoria B: \n\n");
for (linha = 1;linha < (l+1);linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1;coluna < (c+1);coluna++)
    {
        matriz[linha][coluna] = rand()%10;
    }
}
for (linha = 1;linha < (l+1);linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1;coluna < (c+1);coluna++)
    {
        printf("%5d",matriz[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
}

void soma_matriz (int l, int c, M A, M B, M C)
{
int linha;
int coluna;
printf("\nMATRIZ A:\n\n");
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        printf("%5d",A[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
printf("\nMATRIZ B:\n\n");
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        printf("%5d",B[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1);linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1);coluna++)
    {
        C[linha][coluna] = A[linha][coluna] + B [linha][coluna];
    }
}
printf ("\nMatriz resultante da Soma: \n\n");
for (linha = 1;linha < (l+1);linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1;coluna < (c+1);coluna++)
    {
        printf("%5d",C[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    }
}

void multiplicar_matriz (int l, int c, M A, M B, M C)
{
int linha,coluna,temp,acumula;
printf("\nMATRIZ A:\n\n");
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        printf("%5d",A[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
printf("\nMATRIZ B:\n\n");
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        printf("%5d",B[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
printf ("\nMatriz Resultante da Multiplicacao:\n\n");
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1);linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1);coluna++)
    {
        acumula = 0;
        for ( temp = 0; temp < (l+1); temp++)
        {
            acumula = acumula + A[linha][temp] * B[temp][coluna];
        }
        C[linha][coluna] = acumula;
    }
}

for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna ++)
    {
        printf("%5d",C[linha][coluna]);
    }
    printf ("\n\n");
    }
}

void pesquisar_matriz(int l, int c, M A, M B, M SOMA, M MULT)
{

int linha, coluna;
int numero;
int controle = 0;
printf("\nDigite o numero que voce quer buscar: ");
scanf("%d",&numero);
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        if (numero == A[linha][coluna])
        {
            printf("\nEncontrado o numero: %d, na matriz A na posicao A[%d][%d]\n\n",numero,linha,coluna);
            controle = 1;
        }
    }
}

for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        if (numero == B[linha][coluna])
        {
            printf("\nEncontrado o numero: %d, na matriz B na posicao B[%d][%d]\n\n",numero,linha,coluna);
            controle = 1;
        }
    }
}

for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        if (numero == SOMA[linha][coluna])
        {
            printf("\nEncontrado o numero: %d, na matriz de SOMA na posicao SOMA[%d][%d]\n\n",numero,linha,coluna);
            controle = 1;
        }
    }
}
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        if (numero == MULT[linha][coluna])
        {
            printf("\nEncontrado o numero: %d, na matriz de MULTIPLICACAO na posicao MULT[%d][%d]\n\n",numero,linha,coluna);
            controle = 1;
        }
    }
}
if (controle == 0)
printf("\nNumero nao encontrado em nenhuma matriz.\n\n");
}

void verificar_matriz ( int l , int c , M matriz, int *ver)
{
int linha,coluna,controle,tamanho;
controle = 0;
for (linha = 1; linha < (l+1); linha++)
{
    for (coluna = 1; coluna < (c+1); coluna++)
    {
        if (matriz[linha][coluna] == 0)
        controle = controle + 1;
    }
}
tamanho = l*c;
if (controle == tamanho)
*ver = 2;
else
*ver = 1;
}

void sair_menu (int *saida)
{
char i;
printf("\nDeseja executar outra acao? (S/N)\n\n");
scanf ("%c",&i);
if(i == 's')
    *saida = 6;
}

int main ()
{
int l,c,op,saida;
saida = 0;
int ver;
ver = 0;
printf ("\n Digite a quantidade de linhas da matriz: ");
scanf ("%d",&l);
printf ("\n\n Digite a quantidade de colunas da matriz: ");
scanf ("%d",&c);
M matriz1,matriz2,matrizSOMA,matrizMULT;
do
{
printf("\n Escolha uma opcao: \n\n");
printf(" 1 - Cadastrar a primeira matriz aleatoria.\n\n");
printf(" 2 - Cadastrar a segunda matriz aleatoria.\n\n");
printf(" 3 - Somar duas matrizes.\n\n");
printf(" 4 - Multiplicar duas matrizes.\n\n");
printf(" 5 - Pesquisar um numero em uma matriz.\n\n");
printf(" 6 - Sair.\n\n");
scanf("%d",&op);
if (op == 1)
    receber_matriz_ale1(l,c,matriz1);
else if (op == 2)
    receber_matriz_ale2(l,c,matriz2);
else if (op == 3)
{
    verificar_matriz(l,c,matriz1,&ver);
    if (ver == 2)
    receber_matriz_ale1(l,c,matriz1);
    verificar_matriz(l,c,matriz2,&ver);
    if (ver == 2)
    receber_matriz_ale2(l,c,matriz2);
    soma_matriz(l,c,matriz1,matriz2,matrizSOMA);
    sair_menu(&saida);
    if (saida == 6)
        break;
}
else if (op == 4)
{
    verificar_matriz(l,c,matriz1,&ver);
    if (ver == 2)
    receber_matriz_ale1(l,c,matriz1);
    verificar_matriz(l,c,matriz2,&ver);
    if (ver == 2)
    receber_matriz_ale2(l,c,matriz2);
    multiplicar_matriz(l,c,matriz1,matriz2,matrizMULT);
    sair_menu(&saida);
    if (saida == 6)
        break;
}
else if (op == 5)
{
    pesquisar_matriz(l,c,matriz1,matriz2,matrizSOMA,matrizMULT);
    sair_menu(&saida);
    if (saida == 6)
        break;
}
else if (op == 6)
    break;
else
printf ("\nOpcao Invalida.\n\n");
}while (op!=6);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tente isolar o problema, é muito código para analisar.

Comment: O programa salta a parte do Sim ou Não isso msm? Qual é seu SO?

Comment: Por que você não coloca em um switch e usa o default para mandar essa msg ? bem mais pratico.

Comment: A função `sair_menu` está atribuindo 6 ao valor da variável `saida` e o programa encerra quando é informado que existe a necessidade de realizar outra ação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu problema vem do `scanf()` anterior, por exemplo

```
printf ("\n\n Digite a quantidade de colunas da matriz: ");
scanf ("%d",&c);
```

O que acontece quando o utilizador escolhe, por exemplo, 8 colunas é que ele digita `"8"` e `"<ENTER>"`. O `scanf()` 'apanha' o `"8"` (que mete na variavel `c`) e deixa o `"<ENTER>"` 'pendurado' no buffer de entrada.

Quando a seguir tentas ler qualquer coisa do buffer, esse `"<ENTER>"` ainda la esta. Se tentas ler com `scanf("%d", ...)` o `"<ENTER>"` é ignorado por ser *whitespace*; se tentas ler com `scanf("%c", ...)` o programa apanha o `"<ENTER>"` ja que o `"%c"` nao ignora os espacos em branco.

**Sugestao #1**: deixa de usar `scanf()` para *user input* e usa `fgets()` (possivelmente seguido de `sscanf()`)

Sugestao #2: mete um espaco antes do `%c` para fazeres o `scanf()` ignorar espacos em branco: `scanf(" %c", ...)`

---

PS: Verifica sempre se o valor devolvido pelo `sscanf()` (ou funcoes relacionadas) é o esperado

```
if (sscanf(tmp, "%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) /* erro */;
```

Comment: oi, pmg, como você analisou o código do AP e sabe qual é a raiz do problema, seria legal se pudesse dar um upgrade na pergunta pois está acumulando votos para ser fechada. Tipo, o título precisa de ajuda urgente... qual título você daria para descrever o problema e que ajudasse o resto da internet a encontrar *sua* resposta? E também, a gente tem liberdade para ajustar o texto da pergunta de forma até extensa, desde que não prejudique o sentido original nem seja feita para favorecer nossa resposta. abs! ps: tem até uma medalha pra quem responde e edita a pergunta (x vezes)

Comment: Valeu velho, só coloquei o espaço antes do %d no scanf e deu certo. Legal que eu nem imaginava o problema, e agora já tenho uma ideia do que seja. Valeu mesmo.